# Cauchy's problem doubt with the differential equations $y'=2x(y-1)^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following Cauchy's problem
$$\begin{cases}
y'=2x(y-1)^2 \\
y(0)=1
\end{cases}$$
First I notice that $y(x)\equiv1$ is a solution of the differential equation and satisfies the condition $y(0)=1$, so it is a solution of the Cauchy's problem.

Now, for $y(x)\ne1$, I proceed to divide
$$\frac{y'}{(y-1)^2}=2x$$
$$\int_0^x \frac{y'(s)}{(y(s)-1)^2} \text{d}s=\int_0^x 2s \text{d}s$$
$$\left[-\frac{1}{y-1}\right]_0^x=x^2$$
And here comes the problem, the denominator is zero because of $y(0)=1$; what am I doing wrong? I suspect the solution is unique and it is $y(x)\equiv1$, but if it is true I don't know how to prove it by using the uniqueness and existence theorem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Picard–Lindelöf [Existence and Uniqueness Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) applies here to show that $y=1$ is the only
solution.  You just need to verify that this initial value problem satisfies the hypotheses of the theorem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I could use the fact that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous if and only if its derivative is bounded, so $f_y(y,x)=4x(y-1)$ which is bounded in $\mathbb{R}$. Is this correct?

Comment: That's not bounded on all of $\mathbb R^2$, but it is bounded on any rectangle, which is all the theorem needs.